# Text length probability function that peaks for a an average length

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, spline

I am looking at web page to tell what is its content (the main text part) and its title.

I can estimate if I am looking at a title or content by the page's semantics, but wanted to add a rules that look at the lengths. So I am looking for something like the graph on picture below.

The graph should approach `y = 1` at `x = average_length` and then slowly die away.

Ideally, I would like to specify the average content length from `min` to `max`. Maybe a spline?

Would love to hear if you had similar task at hand and how you treated the text length.

Thanks!

[image: text length probability function]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want a [Gamma distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution), or an [Erlang distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erlang_distribution).

They have the kind of shape you showed, and the Gamma distribution has been used to describe lengths of words and sentences, so it seems suitable. Details [here](http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Paper/4101725).

If these probability density functions are too complex for your application, simple approximations could probably be constructed. Ask again if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thats exactly what I need, thanks!